# Disabling mysql strict mode to a specific database

Tags: mysql, database, command

I know it's a bad practice to disable MySQL strict mode.
But for some reasons, I need to disable a specific database and
I have many databases running in MySQL server.
Suppose that I run below command with root user, will it affect to other databases?

```sh
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Because other databases are running in production mode.

Can I disable MySQL strict mode for only a specific database?

Comment: Why not have a secondary YOLO-mode server for this particular requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't change a GLOBAL variable and have it apply to only one database. It always applies globally.

Consider if you could change the variable for one database, which value would it have if you were to run a query using a qualified table name, querying a table across schema boundaries? Or if you ran a query that joins tables from the affected schema and another schema that is not affected?

The workaround you may wish to use is to set `sql_mode` in each session, before executing queries for which you need to have a custom sql mode.